# Is it possible with Drupal Views to have AND and OR in a filter set?

Tags: views

I am attempting to build a view with four filters (A, B, C, D). With Views 3 it is possible to select whether you want these filters to be chained with AND statements or OR statements. Is there a way to configure views so as to chain some of them with AND and others with OR?

For example, ending up with a query that is similar to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM {table} 
WHERE A = 0
  AND B = 0
  AND (C = 1 OR D = 1)`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is entirely possible with the Views 3.x branch. You can create custom Filter groups directly in the Views UI itself, and set the AND/OR for each group separately.

Comment: This is possible in Views 2.x with the [Views OR](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module, but it is much more confusing than the interface in Views 3.x.

Comment: The easiest way to do this in Views 2.x is probably with: http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_query_alter

Comment: Can Views 3.x nest? e.g. ((x OR y) OR (a AND b)) AND (i AND j)

Comment: To answer, my question, you can do that, but you have to duplicate things, e.g. ((x OR y) AND (i AND j)) OR ((a AND b) AND (i AND j)). The other problem is, if some of these conditions are exposed, then you can't do it. Discussed here: https://drupal.org/node/1244772#comment-7430080

Answer (score 0):

If you still wish to use views2 you can write your own filter as I did.

Though, in my case the only requirement was to place `OR field IS NULL` in the query.. 
so it worked for me.. 
i hope it could be extended further.. 
If someone likes the idea.. 
I could upload the code.. here..!!